# Number of digits in $8^n$ in base $6$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Let $d(n)$ be the number of digits when $8^n$ is written in base $6$. Find the closed form expression for $d(n)$.I tested for few numbers:
$$8^1=12$$
$$8^2=144$$
$$8^3=2212$$
So i felt that $d(n)=n$. But to formally prove it, i tried with induction.
Let $d(n)=n$, then we have
$$8^n=a_0a_1a_2....a_{n-1}, \: a_i \in \left\{0,1,2,3,4,5\right\}, \:a_0 \ne 0$$
Now we have
$$8^{n+1}=8^n \times 12$$
I am stuck here?

Comment: You mean you think that $d(n)=n+1$? That's not true, since $8^{20}$ surely is greater than $6^{21}$.

Comment: Hint; what is the number of digits of $6^n$ then what is the number of digits of $x$ for $6^n\le x<6^{n+1}$ ? Can you see how to use $\log_6(x)$ ?

Comment: That's not the answer and it won't work.  $8 = 6 + 2$ so $8^n = (6 + 2)^n = 6^n + .... $ lower terms.  Now for small values of $n$ those lower terms are less than $6^n$ but eventually they will grow and take them.  ... or as you put it $8^{n+1} = 8^n\times 12=8^n\times 6 + 2\times 8^n$. If $8^n$ has $K$ digits then $8^n\times 6$ will have $K+1$ but adding $2\times 8^n$ may eventually force you to carry into at $K+2$ place.

Comment: This is equivalent to $12^{12} = 8,916,100,448,256$ has thirteen digits in base ten. but when we multiply that by $12$ we have $12^{13}=106,993,205,379,072$ has fifteen digits.  Note the leading digit of $8^n$ keeps creeping up. Eventually it will become $5$ and then ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the number of digits of an integer $a$ in base $b$ is $\lfloor\log_b(a)\rfloor+1$ (because it is constant on the interval $[b^k,b^{k+1})$ and jumps by $1$ at values of the form $b^k$).

Hence we want $\lfloor\log_6(8^n)\rfloor+1= \lfloor n\log_6(8)\rfloor +1 = \lfloor n \frac{\ln(8)}{\ln{6}}\rfloor+1$

we have $\frac{\ln{8}}{\ln{6}}\approx 1.16055842$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $8^n = 6^{(\log_6{8})n} = 6^{1.1605\ldots n}.$

So for example, $8^{100} = 6^{116.05...},\ $ so this number has $117$ digits base $6.$

Answer (score 1):

$d(n) = n+1$ only works for small values of $n$.  Note the leading digit is creeping up eventually you will have an $8^k = 5xxxx...x$ with $k+1$ digits but $8^{k+1} = 1yxxxx....x$ with $k + 3$ digits.

Indeed $8^6 = 5341344$ with $7$ digits and $8^7 = 112541012$ with $9$ digits.

=====

You can think *backwards*.  If $8^n$ has $K$ digits then $8^n \ge {1\underbrace{000.....0}_K}_{base\ 6} =6^{K-1}$ and $8^n \le {\underbrace{5555.....5}_K}_{base\ 6}=6^{K}-1$ so $6^{K-1} \le 8^n < 6^K$.

So solve for $K$

> $\log_6 6^{K-1} \le \log_68^n < \log_6 6^K$
>
>   $K-1 \le n\cdot \log_6 8 < K$
>
>   $K-1 = \lfloor n\cdot \log_6 8 \rfloor$
>
>   $K = \lfloor n\cdot \log_6 8 \rfloor